# Split long sting in new lines and check each line first word in java

Tags: java

I have a string that I split based on delimiter on new lines. I'm wondering now how to check the first word `index[0]` what word is but can't find a way to actually go trough the elements and check.

May be my approach is totally wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] stringArr = line.split(">>");
  int ask = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {

        if (stringArr[0].equals("radio")) {
            ask = 10;
        } else if (Objects.equals(stringArr[0], "tv")) {
            ask = 15;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid media.");
        }

    }
  System.out.println(ask);
}
```

Then when I input `radio 3 7210>>tv 4 2345>>radio 9 31000>>`

The output should be:

```
10
15
10
```

Instead - got nothing. Empty line and the program ends.

Comment: There are several problems here, but if you get what you say you get, it means there is code before that does something like `scanner.nextInt()` or `scanner.next()`, and doesn't clean the end-of-line. You should share a [mcve], not just a code snippet.

Comment: This is absolute all code I have

Comment: Where is the definition of `scanner` then? It doesn't print "Invalid media"? Come to think of it, at the very least it should print "0".

Comment: "absolute all code"  I see now.... I would suggest using `startsWith()`... also not `[0]`  - try some debugger (or just add `System.out.println(stringArr[0]);`)

Comment: Sorry my bad that I removed the scanner from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you want:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] stringArr = line.split(">>");
for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
  int ask = 0;
  String[] words = stringArr[i].split(" ");
  if (words[0].equals("radio")) {
      ask = 10;
      System.out.println(ask);
  } else if (words[0].equals("tv")) {
      ask = 15;
      System.out.println(ask);
  } else {
      System.out.println("Invalid media.");
  }
}
```

Input:

`radio 3 7210>>tv 4 2345>>radio 9 31000>>`

Output:

```
10
15
10
```

First of all, I defined the scanner, not sure if you did that but pretty sure you did.

The elements of stringArr will include the random numbers between each `">>"`. That means, in each element, we should create a new list split by `" "` to isolate the `"radio"` and `"tv"` as the first element.

Additionally, I just rewrote the else-if statement that checks if the first word of the phrases separated by "`>>`" is `"tv"` by using the `.equals()` method as your original if statement did.

Finally, since you are printing out a number EACH time the code encounters a `">>"`, we should print out `ask` inside of the for loop.

EDIT:

Moved the `System.out.println(ask)` inside of the if and else-if statements so it will only run with valid media.

Other than that your code worked perfectly :> , let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications!

Comment: Okay, but when is "Invalid media" it adds one addition empty line to the output. How can I remove it?

Comment: Can you provide an example input

Comment: Yes, `radio 3 7210>>tv 4 2345>>walkmen 9 31000>>radio 9 31000>>`

Comment: If you mean it adds an empty line, it adds a 0, you can just move the print statement inside of the if and else if, i will edit my answer

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "radio 9 31000` started to give this error on the last element

Comment: The input ```radio 3 7210>>tv 4 2345>>walkmen 9 31000>>radio 9 31000>>``` doesn't seem to give an error when I run it? It outputs: 10
15
Invalid media.
10

Comment: My mistake just saw it. Sorry. Everything is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: LMAO np happy to help :)

Comment: Hint: no need to split a second time (`split(" ")`); `startsWith()` can be used to test if one string starts with the given parameter - e.gg. `if (strArr[i].startsWith("radio ")`

Comment: oooh i didnt even think of that, nice catch